# Django: get model's fields name

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a table in react that uses as table information from a django backend.

I would like to fetch the table's columns from the API, so I tried updating the model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, default=1, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                            db_column="uid")
    rid = models.IntegerField()
    action = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    table = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "activity"


    @property
    def fields(self):
        return [f.name for f in self._meta.fields]
```

I am trying to use `fields()` as the method to get all the model's "column" names, so that I can place them in the API's response, but it does not work.

How can I get a django model's field names from the model's meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have method that get's all field names inside model class I would suggest to changing `fields` from property to classmethod

```py
class Activity(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL, default=1, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                            db_column="uid")
    rid = models.IntegerField()
    action = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    table = models.TextField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "activity"


    @classmethod
    def get_field_names(cls):
        return [f.name for f in cls._meta.fields]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either get all fields using `get_fields()` or get a specific field using the `get_field('field_name')` function from model `_meta` API.

Usage:

```
fields = model._meta.get_fields()
my_field = model._meta.get_field('field_name')
```

I believe this will return a list of Field objects. To get the value of each field from the instance, use getattr(instance, field.name).

Ref.: [Retrieving all field instances of a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)

Comment: using `get_fields()` I get `(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: aid>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: uid>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: rid>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: action>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: time>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: table>)`. How can I extract the names> in this particular case: uid, rid, action, time ,table?

Comment: you can loop and select whatever you want using the:
`for i in Activity._meta.get_fields(): print(i.name)`
or do any condition you want.